# Reauthenticating user with Firebase in a background task

Tags: flutter, firebase, bgprocessingtask

In my Flutter app, I am trying to execute a BGProcessingTask through the Workmanager package. In the background task, I want to upload some user data to my connected Firebase database. The database connection is successfully established in the app, with a user creating an account in Firebase and data successfully flowing between the app and the database.

However, in the background task (specifically running on iOS), this database connection is not established. My understanding is that this is because the background task doesn't share the same memory with the main app, as it runs in a separate isolate. If I reestablish the Firebase connection in the background task, everything works again.

Currently I am using the `FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword` function to reestablish the connection, but this requires the username and password to be passed to the background task, which I could only manage to do through SharedPreferences. This is presumably not appropriate from the data security perspective.

What is the best way of reestablishing this connection? Or should I look at this differently altogether?